# Custom mass mailing with SendGrid

Tags: django, smtp, sendgrid

I have requirement to send customised(per user) newsletter to thousands of users.

I created a django app which generates custom newsletter content based on user preference. 
I am using SendGrid, and planning to add celery to send newsletter one by one.

Sendgrid docs says:

> Customers should utilize SMTPAPI if this is an option. As with SMTP, 100 messages can be sent with each connection, but there can be 1000 recipients for each message.

Is there anything like --- SengGrid collecting all the emails I throw at them, make SMTP connection and send to user.

Otherwise, as every newsletter is unique based on receiver, I will have to make single SMTP connection for each email, which I think won't work in case of thousands of emails.

Or is there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just set yourself up to use their REST API. I have used that to send thousands of emails per day. http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html

If you are worried about performance then make it into a job with Django [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/)

Comment: That's exactly what I am thinking. But my question is, is giving say 1000s emails one by one to SendGrid, a viable solution?

Comment: Also, why do you recommend SendGrid Web API over SMTP API? Any particular reason?

Comment: It's completely viable. Nothing wrong with that. The idea of putting it through Django Celery was that you wouldn't tie up your web server. The REST API is easier to integrate into a Django Celery situation since all you need is the ability to hit a url.